# Randomizing via color ramp collection linked meshes with same material

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, collections, instances, random

I downloaded a container from blender swap. The container is made of various parts with different modifiers and so on. I am using collection instances to replicate the container, but I would like to have slightly different paint on each of them.
[image]

I tried all outputs of those two nodes circled in yellow, and I could not manage to change the white paint.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Here I share the Object Info>Random
[image]

I would like to have all the metal parts that are white entirely different in the instances, not every mesh as a different random, but all the white metal paint shader randomized as blue and pink.

Thank you

Comment: the *Object Info > Random* returns different values and works for me

Comment: I did that, and I got each door and wall randomized.  I would like to share it, but I can not see the upload image option when I answer here.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! It's strange that you don't see the upload image option. Is it a reputation restriction?! That would be weird. Do you have the option when you edit your question? If yes, you can upload the image there, copy the image links (it's 2 parts), cancel the edit and use it for the answer.

Comment: I shared in the edited post. Maybe is a status thing, but my comment tab does not have any features more than the dialog box.

Comment: You can join the parts of each container, then they have the same object info. If you want to moving parts you can still use rigging.

Comment: Thank you, joinining the meshes helped out.